# How to bind open generic to a null constant?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

How can I achieve the following?

```
Kernel.Bind(typeof(SomeType<>)).ToConstant(null);
```

This line of code will fail because the compiler cannot infer `null` type from the usage. Since I am using an open generic type, I can't pass it in as a generic argument.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Why do you need this? Injecting `null` as a dependency is not a good approach. Consider using the Null Object pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Although I fail to see the reason to do this, particularly since I sincerely doubt that ninject will have any idea how to resolve it, you could create a null instance and bind to that directly.

The following compiles but it won't do what you want at runtime:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();

SomeType<int> constant = null;
kernel.Bind(typeof(SomeType<>)).ToConstant(constant);

public class SomeType<T>{ }
```

It will actually throw an ActivationContext error that is similar to the following:

> ActivationException: Error activating SomeType{int} using
>   binding from SomeType{T} to constant value Provider returned
>   null.

So no, if you want to use a constant value, it needs to be a non-null value in order to be resolved successfully.